# Htaccess URL redirect not working in godaddy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hi I have the following redirection for a friendly URL site

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>        
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    rewritecond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    rewritecond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    rewriterule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

    rewriterule ^noticia/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ noticia.php?title=$1 [L]         
</IfModule>
```

If i go to **www.mysite.com/noticias** or any other URL like that everything goes ok

But if i try to go to **www.mysite.com/noticia/this-is-a-parameter**

When I access a link I do it like `<a href="noticia/this-is-a-parameter">`

I get Internal Server Error message and white screen

In localhost it was working perfectly, but can't find a solution in the server.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: add your apache error.log to your question

Comment: Godaddy shared hosting doesn't have access to that log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for presence of `.php` file before adding php extension and reorder your rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^noticia/([\w-]+)/?$ noticia.php?title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked, so, if i have other files like `products/([\w-]+)/?$... ` do i have to add `RewriteBase /` before each rule? because in those my stylesheets or images doesn't load properly

Comment: Or if i have for instance the same URL with an additional parameter? lets say `^noticia/page/([\w-]+)/?$` ? [See this sample](http://pacificodesign.net/noticias/tag/casas)

Comment: That is due to relative paths being used. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! you saved the day

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this old thread, but what if i need to redirect to another page when there is nothing on the url? for instance, http://example.com/noticias redirects to http://example.com/noticias.php but http://example.com redirects to --> http://example_different_page.com

Comment: It could be a folder on the same site, let's say, http://example.com/beta/index.html The customer wants a beta redirect

Comment: Doesn't work :( here is the actual page [site](http://pacificodesign.net/) and the directory where i shall redirect [redirect folder](http://pacificodesign.net/beta)

Comment: Ok then I suggest creating a new question as asking a question and answering it from comments section is difficult.

Comment: Done, [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767642/htaccess-url-redirect-to-beta-subfolder-while-using-friendly-url-rewrite)