# htaccess URL redirect to beta subfolder, while using friendly URL rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hi I have the following redirection for a friendly URL site

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ /beta/ [L] // Got this from a fellow user in SO but didn't worked
RewriteRule ^home index.php
RewriteRule ^noticia/([\w-]+)/?$ noticia.php?title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^busqueda/([\w-]+)/?$ busqueda.php?item=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^producto/([\w-]+)/?$ producto.php?item=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^noticias/page/([\w-]+)/?$ noticias.php?query=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^noticias/tag/([\w-]+)/?$ noticias.php?query=$1&keyword=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^noticias/search/([\w-]+)/?$ noticias.php?query=$1&keyword=$2 [L,QSA,NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Here is the link to my site

[SITE](http://pacificodesign.net/)

I want that, when an user goes right to that address, gets redirected to a Beta file in a subfolder

[REDIRECT](http://pacificodesign.net/beta/)

What I have so far is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?$ /beta/ [L,R]

RewriteRule ^home index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^noticia/([\w-]+)/?$ noticia.php?title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^busqueda/([\w-]+)/?$ busqueda.php?item=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^producto/([\w-]+)/?$ producto.php?item=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^noticias/page/([\w-]+)/?$ noticias.php?query=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^noticias/tag/([\w-]+)/?$ noticias.php?query=$1&keyword=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^noticias/search/([\w-]+)/?$ noticias.php?query=$1&keyword=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```